# ¿Como hacer un picker en Android desde una lista fija de elementos?

Tags: android, android-layout, datepicker

Necesito una forma de poder seleccionar puntos cardinales mediante algo parecido a un picker.

EL objetivo es indicar el sentido de un evento que puede ser "NORTE-SUR", "ESTE-OESTE"... y los opuestos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya que es una colección inmutable, puedes enumerar los elementos en tu `strings.xml`

```
<string-array name="puntos_cardinales">
<item>NORTE -> SUR</item>
<item>ESTE -> OESTE</item>
<item>TIERRA -> MARTE</item>
</string-array>
```

Y en el layout agregar

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/mi_spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/puntos_cardinales"
    />
```

Si quieres que se abra como popup, usa `android:spinnerMode="dialog"`.

Luego para obtener el valor seleccionado desde la Activity, haces esto:

```
Spinner puntosCardinales =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mi_spinner);
int indice_del_elemento = puntosCardinales.getSelectedItemPosition();
String texto_del_elemento = puntosCardinales.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

Si necesitas volver a establecerlo (por ejemplo en el `onResume` de la actividad)

```
Spinner puntosCardinales =(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mi_spinner);
puntosCardinales.setSelection(indice_del_elemento);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede crear un `DialogFragment`

Definiendo en strings.xml el titulo y los valores:

```
<resources>    
    ...
    ...
    <string name="pick_title">Coordenadas:</string>

    <string-array name="coordenadas">
        <item>NORTE - SUR</item>
        <item>ESTE - OESTE</item>
        <item>SUR - NORTE</item>
        <item>OESTE - ESTE</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Creamos un `DialogFragment` personalizado:

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CoordenadasDialog extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_title)
                .setItems(R.array.coordenadas, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Seleccionada: " +  getResources().getStringArray(R.array.coordenadas)[which] ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

únicamente tenemos que mandar mostrar el DialogFragment:

```
private void muestraPicker() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    CoordenadasDialog miDialogo = new CoordenadasDialog();
    miDialogo.show(fm, "fragmento_coordenadas");
}
```

Este sería el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar clic a un elemento te mostraría un `Toast` con la opción seleccionada.

La otra opción podría ser usando un `Spinner`.